Order only prerequisite not executed by make
I have a rule adddefs.h that needs to be executed before the compiling and linking rules. So I have defined this rule as an order only prerequisite.
........................................
.PHONY: all clean dwn release

all: $(BIN) | adddefs.h 

adddefs.h:
    @echo make adddefs

print:
    @printf "\n################################################################\n"
    @cat adddefs.h
    @printf "\n################################################################\n"

clean:
    @echo CLEANING.......
    @rm -rf ./adddefs.h
    @rm -fr $(OUT)*

dwn:
    fwdwn $(PORT) DS .\$(OUT)\$(NAME)_S.BIN

release:
    cmd /C .\BuildReleases.bat $(APPLICATION_VER)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    @echo LINKING........ $(BIN)
    @$(CCPREF)gcc $(OBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LFLAGS) 
    @echo CONVERTING..... $(NAME).BIN
    @$(CCPREF)objcopy -O binary $(BIN) $(OUT)$(addsuffix .BIN, $(NAME))
    @ls -l $(OUT)$(NAME).BIN
    @$(CCPREF)objdump -x $(BIN) > $(OUT)a.map
    @echo SIGNING........ $(NAME).BIN
    @..\BIN\GENKEY MAC ..\BIN\KEYS\AP.KEY .\OUT\$(NAME).BIN .\OUT\$(NAME)_S.BIN
ifeq ($(DASM), 1)
    @echo DISASSEMBLING.. $(OUT)a.dasm
    @$(CCPREF)objdump -D -S -z $(BIN) > $(OUT)a.dasm
endif
..................................

When I invoke make with make all, adddefs.h isn't executed. adddefs.h doesn't exist.

This:
all: $(BIN) | adddefs.h 

Definitely does not provide the behavior needs to be executed before the compiling and linking rules.  That says that the target adddefs.h will be built before the recipe for the all target is run.  It doesn't say anything about the order of building adddefs.h relative to any other target such as $(BIN) or object files.
If you want the target to be built before any object files, then you must list it as a prerequisite of the object files, not all; adding something like this:
$(OBJ) : | addefs.h

However, I have to say that this is highly unusual (listing a header file as an order-only prerequisite).  If adddefs.h is changed none of the object files (which presumably include it) will be recreated, which seems unlikely to be correct.

When I invoke make with make all, adddefs.h isn't executed. adddefs.h doesn't exist.

I don't think that is true.  What I think is that because adddefs.h isn't created first (as I explained above), your compile and link commands fail and so make gives up and never tries to create adddefs.h.  If the compile and link commands would have succeeded, then make would have built adddefs.h.
